# Change value of one column based on a change in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have an SQL table like this:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | ColA | ColB  |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | red  | false |
+----+------+-------+
```

I would like the value of colA to change to 'blue' when I set the value of colB to 'true', so that I end up with:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | ColA | ColB |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | blue | true |
+----+------+------+
```

I realize that I can simply update both columns, but I was wondering whether it's possible to add a rule in the DB that automatically does this.

I'm using psql 10.4.

Comment: If cola is always `blue` when `colb` is `true`  and always `red` when `colb` is `false` then why store `cola` at all?

Comment: Use [Trigger](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/)

Comment: In my DB there are three possibilities for (colA, colB): (red, false), (blue, true), (blue, false). The trigger is specifically for when colB in (red, false) gets set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Postgresql 10 does not support computed columns, I think you have three options:

1. Define a trigger that updates ColA when ColB is updated.
2. Define a view on top of original table that computes ColA.
3. Forget having ColA in database and compute the value in SELECT.

Comment: It turned out the table structure was based on a misunderstanding. It has been changed, and the question is no longer relevant. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

just use case when, as you not mentioned any logic so assume you want when red then blue and true

```
select id, case when ColA='red' then 'blue' end as ColA,
case when ColA='red' then true end as ColB from t
```